# Unable to expand projected co-ordinate system folder in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system

On trying to re-project any raster from GCS to any PCS, in the "Spatial Reference Properties" window, my "Projected Co-ordinate Systems" folder is not expanding. Where as the GSC folder is expanding. Even I tried to clear the spatial property of the layer and tried to set it to the desired PCS, there also its not expanding.

After restarting ArcMap, before clicking on the ArcToolBox, if I go to layer properties, there it expands. Once I clicled on ArcToolBox, it doesn;t expand either from Layer properties or from Project Raster Tool. I have attached the the image of my window. If at all any one can guide me a solution. Please.. please.. please... I'm stuck almost since last 3 months.

[image: Without opening ArcToolBox, From Layer Properties]

[image: After opening ArcToolBox, from Project Raster tool]

Comment: A possible **workaround**: (since ArcGIS 10.1 projections are stored in a [built-in database](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39488) instead of separate prj files) - As long as all projections are visible, save the desired projection as _prj_-File (add it to _Favorites_ or right-click on it and _Save as_). Later (when the projections are gone), open it manually, either via _Favorites_ or by importing it (click on the globe icon). - A [Python script that saves prj files from ArcGIS defaults](https://gist.github.com/scw/5720029) has been published in the ESRI Forums.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things that you could try (if you haven't already). First is deleting the normal.mxt file. Second is rebuilding the index for the repository containing you projected coordinate system (search windows > search option > index > add your repository)